# Group the rows in a dataframe as per the values

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

Hi I have pandas data frame that has data as follows.

```
   Col1  Col2
0   34   12.5
1   35   12.9
2   36   12.6
3   34   12.5
4   35   13.4
5   35   12.9
6   36   13.7
7   34   12.9
8   35   13.1
9   36   12.7
```

I want to group the rows and the group should reset when ever the consecutive column values dont increment. The output should be like this

Output:

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3
0   34   12.5   1
1   35   12.9   1
2   36   12.6   1
3   34   12.5   2
4   35   13.4   2
5   35   12.9   3
6   36   13.7   3
7   34   12.9   4
8   35   13.1   4
9   36   12.7   4
```

Any help appreciated.